# SQL Server job - powershell Where does "log to table" save logs

Tags: sql-server, powershell

[image]

After selecting the "log to table" option and running the job, when I come back to this screen and select View, I can see the output of the powershell script in a text file.

The only job step is a call to a powershell script that takes a string as input and prints it after performing a `toUpper`

However, where are these logs being stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The F1 key for help docs reveals that the execution result is stored in the `sysjobstepslogs` table of the `msdb` database.

Comment: Thanks, I dont have help configured correctly I think, pressing F1 leads to help about the help viewer :)